# GROUP BY Clause based on the condition

Tags: mysql, group-by

I want to produce one excel report based on the query. In that i have Job number and Status. I just want to group by status for the Job number and then order by job number.

Here is the query for the report ,

```
SELECT DISTINCT
JobNumber.JOB_NO AS JobNumber,
CONCAT(ADDRESS.LOT,' ', ADDRESS.UNIT_NUMBER,' ', ADDRESS.STREET_NUMBER,' ',ADDRESS.STREET_NAME,' ', ADDRESS.SUBURB,' ', ADDRESS.STATE,' ', ADDRESS.POST_CODE) As JobAddress,
Builder.TITLE As Builder,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(Type.Title) SEPARATOR ', ') AS EstimationType,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(Mode.Title) SEPARATOR ', ') AS RequestMode,
Status.Title AS Status,
EstimationRequest.Notes,
EstimationRequestOrder.Notes As OrderNotes,
EstimationRequestQuote.Notes AS QuoteNotes,
EstimationRequestSale.Notes AS SaleNotes,
EstimationRequestMasterBOQ.Notes AS MasterNotes,
EstimationRequest.EstimatedTime,
EstimationRequest.ActualTime,
EstimationRequest.BillableTime,
EstimationRequest.AssignedToID,
CONCAT(AssignedTo.FIRST_NAME,' ',AssignedTo.LAST_NAME) AS AssignedTo,
Operator.USER_NAME As Operator

FROM
EstimationRequest

INNER JOIN EstimationType
        ON EstimationType.EstimationRequestID = EstimationRequest.ID AND EstimationType.Inactive = '0'

 LEFT OUTER JOIN Lookup Type
        ON Type.ID = EstimationType.TypeID AND Type.EntityType = 'ESTIMATIONTYPE'

INNER  JOIN RequestMode
        ON RequestMode.EstimationRequestID = EstimationRequest.ID AND RequestMode.Inactive = '0'

LEFT OUTER  JOIN Lookup Mode
        ON Mode.ID = RequestMode.ModeID AND Mode.EntityType = 'REQUESTMODE'


LEFT OUTER JOIN JOB JobNumber
        ON JobNumber.JOB_ID = EstimationRequest.JobID 

LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESS
    ON ADDRESS.ENTITY_ID = EstimationRequest.JobID AND ADDRESS.ENTITY_TYPE = 'JOB'

LEFT OUTER JOIN Lookup Status
        ON Status.ID = EstimationRequest.StatusID AND Status.EntityType = 'Status'

LEFT OUTER JOIN JOB 
        ON JOB.JOB_ID = EstimationRequest.JobID

LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPANY AS Builder
        ON Builder.COMPANY_ID = JOB.COMPANY_ID

 LEFT OUTER JOIN USER AS Operator
        ON Operator.USER_ID = EstimationRequest.OperatorID

LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE AS AssignedTo
        ON AssignedTo.EMPLOYEE_ID = EstimationRequest.AssignedToID

LEFT OUTER JOIN  EstimationRequestOrder
        ON EstimationRequestOrder.EstimationRequestID = EstimationRequest.ID AND EstimationRequestOrder.Inactive = '0'

LEFT OUTER JOIN  EstimationRequestQuote
        ON EstimationRequestQuote.EstimationRequestID = EstimationRequest.ID AND EstimationRequestQuote.Inactive = '0'

LEFT OUTER JOIN  EstimationRequestSale
        ON EstimationRequestSale.EstimationRequestID = EstimationRequest.ID AND EstimationRequestSale.Inactive = '0'

LEFT OUTER JOIN  EstimationRequestMasterBOQ
        ON EstimationRequestOrder.EstimationRequestID = EstimationRequest.ID AND EstimationRequestMasterBOQ.Inactive = '0'

GROUP BY EstimationRequest.JobID ORDER BY JobNumber.JOB_NO
```

I have status New,In Progress ,On Hold and Completed. When I give Group by clause for status, it would return only four rows but i have 11 rows with different statuses. I just need to Order columns -  Job Number group by status and order by job number.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you need to group by both `JobID` and `Status`.

Comment: If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query